# Did the discovery of Akkadian texts written in Ugaritic script affect our knowledge of Akkadian?

Tags: cuneiform, akkadian, hurrian, ugaritic

Besides Ugaritic, Hurrian and Akkadian texts, written in Ugaritic alphabetic script, were also discovered at Ras Shamra.<sup>1</sup>

My question is straightforward: did the discovery of Akkadian texts written out in an alphabetic script (albeit minus the vowels) affect our understanding of Akkadian? Did it clarify or complicate the pronunciation of any words? Or did it just confirm things we already knew?

I'm most interested in the impact of our understanding of Akkadian, but if you had additional remarks on any of the cuneiform language, I'd be happy to hear them as well.

---

<sub>1. Tropper & Vita 2019, "Ugaritic," in *The Semitic Languages*, by Huehnergard & Pat-El edd. 2nd Ed. Routledge: 2019.</sub>

Comment: "our understanding" is hyperbole, if I understand correctly it was discovered a lifetime ago.

Comment: "Our" doesn't have to mean only we in the present day.